# What are the right max values for the video size

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

at the moment im fighting with this bug here bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19972
during this i run into a mistake in the fb-documentation about the maximum sizes of embeded video.

this page says that the video can be max 398px in width and height developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/

although the description of the opengraph defines the it as follows 
    og:video:width - e.g. "385" (max 398)
    og:video:height - e.g. "400" (max 460)
developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

does anybody knows what the right values are?

Thanks in advance
Nick

Answer (score 0):

As of today the max height seems to have silently slipped back to 259, which it used to be a long time ago. No response from Facebook. It breaks existing embeds (that is to say, embeds made today which worked recently).

Comment: HI Carl, thanks for your answer. But i think the 259 px is just a bug from facebook. it only happens when i share the flash content with the new FB-Share App. when i share the content with the old api it works fine.